# Universal grid 5X5 km

Tags: grids-graticules, mapping

I'm looking for a universal world grid of 5X5 km or 10X10 kms.
Is there any known reference in place? And is it possible to get the data ?

Comment: You could create one yourself?

Comment: I actually wrote ArcPy code to generate one.  The trick is that 5x5km isn't possible. Instead I found a delta longitude near 32N that was roughly 5km, and evenly divided 360 degrees by a multiple of 64, then constructed a rectangular grid with variable height so that each rectangle has geodesic area of 25km (to within 0.01%). Each polygon was encoded with the IDs of parent 100sqkm, 400sqkm,.. cells, up six tessellations. 20M polygons covers the level 6 tiles over land. It took an hour or two to run.

Comment: Thank you so much for the leads.That should be working for me.

Comment: Might also be worth while to investigate H3 developed by Uber. https://eng.uber.com/h3/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with any GIS tools like :

- GRASS GIS : with v.mkgrid

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.mkgrid.html or

- QGIS :
  Menu Vector => Search Tools > Create grid
  Or in processing toobox
- I am sure it exists in commercial software like ArcGIS or MapInfo

Main problem is what you define by "universal grid" ? it will depend on projection you would like to have it ... WGS84 ? EPSG:3857? local UTM ?

(If UTM, Klas Karlsson [ https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/55741/klas-karlsson ] have a usefull video tuto here :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdBwyeCG3Ug )

Comment: Can confirm, in Esri software this is possible and about as simple as in Q. There's even the option for an ad hoc grid that renders in the map canvas without being its own layer, and will generate graticules for any extent, even if you pan beyond 180 degrees.

Comment: @JoshC can you share 5/10/50/100 km grids for the world as created by Esri? QGIS or Grass does not seem to have that capability, they all start with requirement to "select suitable local projected coordinate system" and there is none for the world or continental scale. Of course poles should be excluded and the polygons would be is somewhat approximation, not clean rectangles in most(any) projection.